# How to use a SUM result in the same query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a following SQL statement:

```sql
SELECT `activities`.`user_id`,
       `users`.`firstname`,
       `users`.`lastname`,
       Sum(activities.energy)   AS energy,
       Sum(activities.distance) AS distance
FROM   `activities`
       INNER JOIN `users`
               ON `activities`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
WHERE  `activities`.`activity_type_id` = ?
GROUP  BY `activities`.`user_id`
ORDER  BY `energy` DESC
```

This gets me an array of users, with calculated sums of distance and energy, from activities they performed (sorted by energy). I'm using it for displaying rankings.

What I would like to do, is to get get user position (placement in rankings) by activity-type and/or city_id.

To do this I must first calculate SUM of his energy by activity_type_id and then get his index from resulting query. Is it possible to do something like this with one query. Or do I have to get all users and then work with an array to get proper placement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to take a look into subqueries.

https://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/subqueries_part_1.html

Update :

For example, a SUM result into a query.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE
field = ( SELECT SUM(otherField) as energy
          FROM `table2`
)
```